# Why give me error?

Tags: haskell

Error:

`` ERROR file:.\2.hs:6 - Syntax error in declaration (unexpected `(') ``

Code:

```
frist (y:ys)= (y:ys) !! 0

remove1 (y:[]) = []
remove1  (y:y2:ys) = if  y==y2 then remove1 (y:ys) else [y2] ++ remove1 (y:ys)

count&remove (x:xs) = length (x:xs) - length (remove1 (x:xs))

makepairlist [] = []
makepairlist l = [(count&remove l , y)] ++ makepairlist l
```

Comment: The `:6` after the filename means the error is on line 6

Comment: You can not use `&` in the middle of an identifier. Replace it with some other character.

Answer (score 3):

The cause for the error you're getting here is the use of the name `count&remove`: identifiers in Haskell have to be either alphanumeric (e.g. `count_and_remove`) *or* symbolic (e.g. `==`, `++`, etc.).  Identifiers can't contain both alphanumeric characters and symbols.

But that's just one problem.  You also have a reference to `y` on line 9 that doesn't refer to anything.  And you seem not to quite understand yet how pattern matching works in function definitions.  For example, your `first` function could be defined just as:

```
first (x:xs) = x
```

This isn't great in itself, both because there's a standard Prelude function called `head` that does this, and because it's what's called a *partial function* (https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_functions).

The same sort of comment applies to your `count&remove` function, which you could write as:

```
count_and_remove xs = length xs - length (remove1 xs)
```

(No need to pattern match with `(x:xs)` here.)

If you are looking for more learning resources, a popular tutorial is [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).  You can also ask for help on the [haskell-beginners mailing list](https://mail.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/beginners) or have a conversation in the `#haskell` channel on [irc.freenode.net](https://webchat.freenode.net/).